# Avoid object null reference exception when accessing sub-elements that may or may not exist

Tags: c#, .net, exception, linq-to-xml, nullreferenceexception

I  have:
An XML with some elements.
A sub-element that may or may not be defined inside this XML. 
Need to extract the value of the sub-element when it does exist.

How do I get the value without throwing object-reference errors?

For example:

```
 string sampleXML = "<Root><Tag1>tag1value</Tag1></Root>"; 

//Pass in <Tag2> and the code works: 
//string sampleXML = "<Root><Tag1>tag1value</Tag1><Tag2>tag2Value</Tag2></Root>";    
 XDocument sampleDoc = XDocument.Parse(sampleXML);

//Below code is in another method, the 'sampleDoc' is passed in. I am hoping to change only this code
XElement sampleEl = sampleDoc.Root; 
string tag1 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleEl.Element("Tag1").Value) ? "" : sampleEl.Element("Tag1").Value;

//NullReferenceException:
//Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
string tag2 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleEl.Element("Tag2").Value) ? "" : sampleEl.Element("Tag2").Value;
```

Comment: thanks everyone! I didn't expect so many people would help me out (and in such a short span of time). I wish I could mark all of your answers correct but I have upvoted your answer. I have encountered Null reference exceptions in a variety of situations, will save that for another day :)

Comment: As a remark: This is one of the rare occasions where life is easier with Visual Basic: `Dim tag2 = sampleXML.Root.<Tag2>.Value`. The `<Tag2>` property returns a (possibly empty) collection of XElements, and the `Value` extension method returns the string value of the first item or `Nothing` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should check if the document is null, remember you are accessing the .Value and this will throw a null reference exception so before you apply .value do a test:

```
if (sampleEl != null)
  //now apply .value
```

Or ternary:

```
string tag2 = sampleEl.Element("Tag2") != null ? sampleEL.Element("Tag2").Value : String.Empty
```

Your code then becomes:

```
 string sampleXML = "<Root><Tag1>tag1value</Tag1></Root>"; 

    //Pass in <Tag2> and the code works: 
    //string sampleXML = "<Root><Tag1>tag1value</Tag1><Tag2>tag2Value</Tag2></Root>";    
     XDocument sampleDoc = XDocument.Parse(sampleXML);

    //Below code is in another method, the 'sampleDoc' is passed in. I am hoping to change only this code
    XElement sampleEl = sampleDoc.Root; 
    string tag1 = sampleEl.Element("Tag1") != null ? sampleEl.Element("Tag1").Value : String.Empty;

    //NullReferenceException:
    //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
string tag2 = sampleEl.Element("Tag2") != null ? sampleEL.Element("Tag2").Value : String.Empty
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [null-coalescing-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for a shortcut:

```
 string tag1= (string)sampleEl.Element("Tag1") ?? string.Empty;
```

This also uses the fact that LINQ to XML allows the cast operation to get the value of the element (in this case cast to string), but returns `null` if the element does not exist.

Comment: Very nice... I didn't know you could cast an XElement to a string

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check for `null` in order to prevent them.  Given the repeated pattern you're using I would just factor this off into an extension method.

```
public static string GetElementValue(this XElement parent, string elementName) {
  if (parent == null) { 
    return string.Empty;
  }
  var element = parent.Element(elementName);
  if (element == null || element.Value == null) {
    return string.Empty;
  }
  return element.Value;
}
```

Now your above code can be replaced with the following

```
string tag1 = sampleEl.GetElementValue("Tag1");
string tag2 = sampleEl.GetElementValue("Tag2");
```

Comment: In the method definition above, 'return element.Value.ToString()' will that be needed since I'm using everything as a string. Or is 'Value' already a string type?

Comment: @Amy: Yes, it's a string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The C# ternary operator is pretty good for this:

```
string tag2 = sampleEl.Element("Tag2") == null ? "" : sampleEl.Element("Tag2").Value;
```

Comment: @JonH: Why? [...I don't like the min 15 char requirement...]

Comment: @Heinzi - Its a personal preference.  I don't like seeing code with a bunch "" "" "" "" "" "" "" in it.  Seeing a constant is much more readable.

Comment: @Heinzi: It doesn't make any significant difference to how the code runs. Just use whichever you find most readable (just like where you prefer to place your braces)

Answer (score 1):

```
string tag1 = sampleEl.Element("Tag1") != null ? sampleEl.Element("Tag1").Value : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this extension method. It requires you to specify the property to access as a lambda, and a default value to use if the actual value or anything up the chain is null:

```
public static TOut ValueOrDefault<TIn, TOut>(this TIn input, Func<TIn, TOut> projection, TOut defaultValue)
        where TOut : class
    {
        try
        {
            return projection(input) ?? defaultValue;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var value = topObject.ValueOrDefault(x=>x.ChildObject.AnotherChild.ChildProperty, String.Empty);
```

`value` will be the empty string if topObject, ChildObject, AnotherChild, or ChildProperty are null. If all of those are valid references, the return will be whatever ChildProperty actually is (which could still be the empty string). The catch for the NullReferenceException handles references of child members of a null reference. For nullable types, InvalidOperationException is thrown when accessing the Value property of a null nullable type.

Comment: You can use `default(T)` to avoid using constraint

Comment: Yes. I have an overload that just returns default(TOut) as well, but I thought this might be more useful as it looks like he wants the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

C# 6.0 allows us to make the expression shorter and simpler:

```
 string uniqueIdentifier = myNode.Document?.Element("elem1")?.Element("elem2")?.Attribute("attribute1")?.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, here's a solution using LINQ to XML which

- requires only one statement and
- does not need the ternary operator, so you don't need to specify the name of the tag twice:

  ```
  string tag1 = sampleEl.Elements("Tag1").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
  string tag2 = sampleEl.Elements("Tag2").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
  ```

Add `?? ""` if you want the empty string instead of `null` if the tag does not exist.

Comment: If sampleEl.Elements("Tag1") is null, this is still going to blow up. The source of a Linq operator cannot be null.

Comment: @KeithS: Note that I wrote `Elements`, not `Element`. `Elements` returns an `IEnumerable(XElement)`, which is never null. It might be empty, in which case Select will also return an empty IEnumerable and FirstOrDefault will return null (as desired).